# Basic Ruby: Returning a value in a string

Tags: ruby

In my teamtreehouse ruby course I am on this challenge and for some reason my solution is not clearing the challenge. What am I doing wrong

**Question:**
In the previous challenge, we wrote a method that returned the remainder of two arguments when divided. That's cool, but it would be nicer if the method returned the remainder in a nice full sentence. Use string interpolation to return the remainder inside the sentence “The remainder of a divided by b is c.” where a is your “a” variable, b is your “b” variable, and c is the value of a % b.

**My Answer**

```
def mod(a, b)
  c = a % b
  puts "The remainder of #{a} divided by #{b} is #{c}"
end
```

**Note**
We can only use two arguments

Comment: `"The remainder of 4 divided by 3 is 1" != "The remainder of 4 divided by 3 is 1."` (note the fullstop) Does that fix it?

Comment: Your method doesn't return a string. It prints a string with `puts` and then returns the value returned by `puts`, which is always `nil`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to print and return your sentence:

```
def mod(a, b)
  c = a % b
  ret = "The remainder of #{a} divided by #{b} is #{c}"
  puts ret
  return ret
end
```

If you don't need to print out the sentence, you could do this:

```
def mod(a, b)
  c = a % b
  "The remainder of #{a} divided by #{b} is #{c}"
end
```

**Ruby functions return the last value (if there's no earlier return statement) and `puts` returns `nil` always:**

```
irb(main):003:0> puts "my sentence"
my sentence
=> nil
irb(main):004:0>
```

Answer (score 1):

Modified previous answer and this worked for me :

`def mod(a, b)
  c = a % b
  ret = "The remainder of #{a} divided by #{b} is #{c}."
  return ret
end
puts mod(10, 3)`

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add the period to the end of the sentence, that's why it didn't pass. Also change `puts` to `return`. I'm on the same challenge question and figured out my error.